# Spring boot view is not accessing register.jsp file instead it is printing register string on page

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to make a starter Springboot application and have been scratching my head over this, I will provide the code and structure and explain the problem below:

my applications.properties file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

my registrationController.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registerMe() {
        return "register";
    }

}
```

and register.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="userDetails">
    UserName : <input id="name" name="name"/>
    Email ID : <input id="email" name="email"/>
    Password : <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    Mobile Number : <input id="number" name="number"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register Me"/>
       
    
    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version> <!-- Specify the version you want to use -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image: My folder structure]

When I try to run with this with the default login and the console password I am getting white label error `Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.` And when I try with @RestController instead of @Controller I am able to print "register" as a string but still not as a JSP file, which is what I want to achieve. Any suggestions?